# how can we fetch value of data in line feed manner by using xslt

Tags: xslt

here i have pasted a sample xml of 50G, earlier i used fetch the data from this below tag with the help of using crlf but now i want to fetch by using line feed ,because i need data correctly what if i ask like suppose **i want linefeed 1 content means AE012345677890**
similarly **line feed 2 means it should fetch Bank code** by using xslt how do i can call line feed .

```
<local>
        <message>
            <block4>

                <tag>
                    <name>50G</name>                     
            <value>AE012345677890
    Bank code
    country name
    country code</value>
                </tag>

            </block4>
        </message>
    </local>
```

output required :

AE012345677890,Bank code,country name,country code

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously bad use of XML. The point of XML is that you shouldn't need any other parsing and here you do need one, namely splitting on newline. Anyway, when you already have that, you can split on newline using the core XPath functions `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

First line should be something like

```
substring-before(value, '&#10;')
```

(that's an xpath expression, so you have to put it into  or similar tag) and the remaining lines should be

```
substring-after(value, '&#10;')
```

You can combine these two, so second line is

```
substring-before(substring-after(value, '&#10;'), '&#10;')
```

third line is

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(value, '&#10;'), '&#10;'), '&#10;')
```

etc.

PS: I am not sure whether you need to use `&#10;` or `\n` for newline.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can also do this using the `tokenize` function:

```
<xsl:template match="value">
  <!-- loop through each segment that's before a line break, output 
       its normalised value and add a comma if required -->
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&#10;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(current())"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This produces the desired result:

```
AE012345677890,Bank code,country name,country code
```

(As Dimitre Novatchev points out below, it will also collapse multiple white space, ie: spaces and tabs inside each line, into one single space, so you might want to experiment and see if that's okay with your data)

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, you may be able to implement the EXSLT library which also contains `tokenize` (see the [tokenize page](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) and click on "How To" in the upper lefthand menu for more information on implementing the library).

Comment: This deletes all intermediate spaces leaving only one -- may not be the wanted action. My XSLT 2.0 solution preserves intemediate whitespace -- actually does a "trim".

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I take your point about the use of `normalize-space` so I've edited my response to point out that potential issue. Having said that, the stated problem concerns items (bank code, country name and country code) where that might not be an issue. I was primarily aiming for a succint solution the original poster would easily understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Depending on the value space for the different constituent types** (e.g. if it is known that they don't contain a space), **one of these simple XSLT 1.0 solutions may be what you need**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="value">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "translate(., '&#10; &#9;&#13;', ',')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Produces**:

```
AE012345677890,Bankcode,countryname,countrycode
```

**And this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="value">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "normalize-space(translate(., '&#10;', ','))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces**:

```
AE012345677890, Bank code, country name, country code
```

If none of these two XSLT 1.0 transformation satisfies your requirements, you may need to perform a `trim` operation. There is a **[`trim`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/trim.xsl?view=markup)** function/template in **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** -- ready to use.

**II. A quick XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="value">
  <xsl:variable name="vLines" select="tokenize(., '&#xd;?&#xa;')"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vLines">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "translate(replace(., '(^[ \t\r]+)|([ \t\r]+$)', '~~'), '~', '')"/>
     <xsl:if test="not(position() eq last())">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces exactly the wanted result**:

```
AE012345677890,Bank code,country name,country code
```